# OAuth2 Signin from a Bot, based on Enterprise Bot template(v4 SDK), does not work with MS Teams desktop app

Tags: templates, botframework, bots, enterprise

I have a bot which is based on enterprise bot template(Bot builder framework SDK v4.0). I have called AuthenticationDialog (OAuth2 sign-in with AAD v2) as per other thread in the stack overflow, i have implemented to handle Invoke Activity with "signin/verifyState" in my IBot implementation , it works fine on Microsoft Teams Web app, however, MS Teams desktop app puts up the dialog for selecting sign-in user, immediately, it closes the dialog and sends the Invoke activity with signin/verifyState with "{ "state": "123456"} , i am displaying user to enter the state, when user enters, it works. 
Is it a bug in the Desktop MS Teams app 
(or) I am doing something wrong.

From my bot, I don't use the following line which is in the SDK sample:

```
await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken)
```

In Slack same code works like this, bot puts up the sign-in dialog, when user clicks on Sign-In, browser display the sign-in option where user can select specific user name  account, after successful login, it display the screen with:
Please enter this validation code into the chat window to complete the sign-in:
123456
When user enters the code, automatically TokenResponse is given to the bot.

In TeamsAuth sample, Startup.cs calls 
    `// Create the bot as a transient. 
    services.AddTransient<IBot, TeamsBot<MainDialog>>();`
In my bot calls 
services.AddBot<>()
any idea how it can be done on my case?

Comment: This is likely related to [this issue in GH](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5482). MS Teams *should* auto-close the window and send the magic code for you, by design. Other than the auto-close, are you having issues logging in? To get auth working in Teams, you need to follow [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth). Please share or link to your code if you would like help debugging.

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, my issue is same as the issue in GH. My problem is that my bot is based on enterprise bot template where services.AddBot is called whereas in sample, it calls </br>~~~services.AddTransient<IBot, TeamsBot<MainDialog>>()~~~ How do i make changes for bot based on enterprise bot template.

Comment: I don't believe that makes a difference with this particular issue. Can you please share or link your code? Feel free to email to the address in my profile. The problem is likely that your code doesn't follow the sample I linked in my first comment, particularly the [Teams Activity Handler](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/TeamsActivityHandler.cs)

Comment: @mdrichardson, I will prepare a test project based on enterprise bot template and share it with you, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have it working well with OAuthPrompt & Azure Bot Service in both Teams desktop and mobile.

Here is [my code](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot/blob/master/zyin.intentbot/Bot/DialogBot.cs) for your reference. Check it out and see whether similar code works for you.

BTW The new suggested way of adding bot is to register it using `services.AddTransient<IBot, TBot>()`. Try to avoid using `AddBot`.

Comment: my bot is built on enterprise bot template, so i need to find a workaround solution for enterprise bot.

Comment: in your sample code, what is the message that calls OAuth2 dialog

Comment: @Snekithan - sorry for the late response. Was a bit busy recently. I've updated my code with an auth sample (load graph profile). You simply derive your context from AuthIntentContext instead of IntentContext. [Here is the Example](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot/blob/master/sample/Areas/WhoAmIIntent.cs). Trigger is "who am i"

Comment: it works on webchat and emulator, but not in Teams. For teams, it displays "Authentication required- we need you to sign in to proceed with this task" message. When I clicked "Click to sign in", nothing happens. Teams manifest file looks right, "token.botframework.com" is set in additional valid domains.

Comment: Can you check whether your Teams app registration is using the same bot id as what you registered in the Azure Bot Service (Capabilities -> Bots -> Bot id from App Studio)?
If yes please recreate the Teams app registration and use the same bot id.

Comment: Kindly note you'll have to use "connect to a different bot id" and paste the bot id in if your initial bot id is not created in teams.

Comment: if i don't set appid correctly, i would not get your welcome screen, i am getting welcome screen and whoami turns response, infact hovering over click to signin shows the "https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=3fb.."

Comment: @Snekithan - yes you are right. I cannot think of any other reasons. I'd suggest you grab the link from the auth button and try to access it in the browser (likely not pleasant since you'll have to type the url manually). If that works, this at least can isolate it to the Teams client.