# OAuth sign In button not working on Teams

Tags: botframework

I have `OAuth` cards to let the user sign in. The `OAuth` card renders and works properly on the emulator, but when I publish it to the teams the `OAuth` card renders but the sign in button click doesn't work.

I tried following the following [link](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4768#issuecomment-404964005) to overcome this. But how will I register my bot in the startup file.

The Link says to register like this

```
services.AddBot<YourBot>(options =>
{
    options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);

    options.Middleware.Add(new TeamsAuthWorkaroundMiddleware());
});
```

but I am trying to register like this :

```
services.AddBot<YourBot<Dialog>>(options =>
{
    options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);

    options.Middleware.Add(new TeamsAuthWorkaroundMiddleware());
});
```

the later one doesn't work. Has someone faced this and solved this ?

Comment: As per [Authenticate a user in a Microsoft Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-bot-aad#sign-the-user-in), you need to add the domain of your authentication redirect URL to the validDomains section of the manifest. If you don't, the login popup will not appear.You need to have a manifest file zipped and uploaded as a custom app into Microsoft Teams. In that manifest file you have to specify the domain of the Bot Framework token endpoint:

"validDomains": [ "token.botframework.com" ]

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be related to the bot, but rather your Teams app registration.
For the OAuthPrompt to work with Azure Bot Service, you need to tell Teams to allow token.botframework.com for your app.

Can you try to add token.botframework.com to the "valid domains" of your app? If you are using App Studio, it's in Finish->Domains and Permissions->Valid domains.

Comment: can you elaborate on "card renders but the sign in button click doesn't work"?

Comment: BTW I am not sure what ```TeamsAuthWorkaroundMiddleware``` does. Here is [my bot code](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot/blob/master/zyin.intentbot/Bot/DialogBot.cs) to handle teams auth, hope it helps - just in case.

Comment: When I click on SignIn button on oAuth card , nothing happens

Comment: @AshishKumar can you please check [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663234/oauth2-signin-from-a-bot-based-on-enterprise-bot-templatev4-sdk-does-not-wor/57703814?noredirect=1#comment102535862_57703814) I am having on this with a different user.

Don't want to repeat the same info in two different places.