OAuth Card [No dialogs] does not work in MS Teams client. Works in Emulator and WebChat
What i am trying to do?
I am trying to display a OAuth Card to the user to sign in, and fetch the access JWT token  so that i can use it to impersonate him/her in my Teams Bot. The App configurations and the Bot have been configured as per the following link exactly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=python%2Cpython-sample
Current State
I am not using the Dialogs feature of the SDK, rather, i send the OAuth card directly like the following.
    async def dispatch_signin_card(self, turn_context):
        oauth_card = OAuthCard(
            text="Sign in to continue",
            connection_name=self.connection_name,
            buttons=[
                CardAction(
                    type=ActionTypes.signin, 
                    title="Sign in"
                    )
                ]
            )
        
        await turn_context.send_activity(
            Activity(attachments=[CardFactory.oauth_card(oauth_card)]))

Everytime there is a message (on_message_activity) i check if the turn_context object has a token to make a decision of sending a new signin card. like the following
    async def get_token(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        # Try to get the token from the token exchange or from a prior sign-in
        token_response = None

        # Check if the activity contains a token response
        if turn_context.activity.value and "token" in turn_context.activity.value:
            token_response = TokenResponse(token=turn_context.activity.value["token"])

        if not token_response:
            # If no token in the activity, try to retrieve it from the OAuth connection
            token_response = await turn_context.adapter.get_user_token(turn_context, self.connection_name)

        return token_response

The Card functions perfectly in the Emulator as shown below and in the web chat from the Azure Bot Interface.

It does not work in Teams, neither in the Desktop Client or the Web Client. It gives me the following error.

What have i tried already

I have tried adding *.botframwework.com, token.botframework.com, my ngrok instance url, and graph.microsoft.com to the valid Domains list, as i read them on various support articles.
I have tried triple checking my App Registrations, and their configurations if they have been configured correctly.
I have tried mannually generating the signin link, but cannot decipher how to the OAuth link is generated. I have noticed that everytime a new link is generated, it takes the form https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=some_ids
I have also read many posts which talk about waiting for a bit (4 Hours), before the changes to an App Manifest are actually reflected on Teams. (Not the problem unfortunately).
I tried inspecting traffic on my ngrok instance, when i click the signin button from teams. There is no activity whatsoever.

I am good with honestly any more directions for my investigation. I ran out of ideas and thought of posting a question here (in hopes of not having it marked as duplicate), to help me solve this error.
BTW, i use the package botbuilder-integration-aiohttp==4.15.0.
Update 1

It seems to be the case that the OAuth card does not trigger any event when clicked from MS Teams. I have tried changing the ACtivityHandler to TeamsActivityHandler. I would expect a "NOT IMPLEMENTED" error atleast in the console, which is not the case.
I tried setting up breakpoints after overriding on_turn, on_teams_signin_verify_state, on_teams_action_card_invoke and even on_event but they are not hit, when i click the Sign-In button from teams. This makes me believe that there is no support for dispatching OAuthCards outside the Dialogs paradigm.

Update 2

OAuth Cards do not seem to be supported inherently (without Dialogs and the OAuthPrompt) in MS Teams Channel. The sources of OAuthPrompt show it confiuring the OAuthCard, quite extensively.
It is maybe not clear in the documentation that this card should be used in conjuction with OAuthPrompt for Microsoft teams channel. The card working standalone in other channels does not help resolve the confusion.
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues


also noticed that when i pass the url manually, in the value parameter of the OAuthCard, Teams tries to open a windw, but the token itself is not passed, but i do not know if i need to explore more in this direction.

Maybe session is not getting stored or you need to provide more permissions.

@Shub I dont quite understand what you meant by sessions, being stored .. Regarding the Permissions, the app has been configured correctly, i believe.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58045982/20285541
Maybe you need to ask Teams to provide permission.

@Shub Thanks for the suggestion. I added that already, like mentioned in my question. :)

@AvidJoe-Could you please share the error log so that we can investigate from our end.
Meanwhile we are tried the below sample which is working fine.Could you please check with this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-all-cards/nodejs
https://i.sstatic.net/5x7d95HO.png

@Sayali-MSFT Thanks. :) That sample is in JS but seems like it is only aimed at displaying the cards and not aimed at implementing their functionalty. Ther is no errors or logs, as mentioned before

Are you looking for this-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-complete-auth/nodejs
